# Symbunt Report: I need Advanced time period option

Tags: civireport

I want to track who has donated to our non-profit through a time period (2010-2013) but want to exclude donors who have given since 2014-present.

Answer (score 3):

First create 2 groups, one for donors for time period 2010-2013 and the second for period 2014-present.

Then go to Search - Custom Searches - Include / Exclude Search

Then choose group 1 as "include group" and group 2 as "exclude group" and click Search.

The result will contain exactly the people you want.
It would make sense to add them to a third group, so you can send them a Mailing or whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 1):

Catorghans has one correct answer, and I think this is preferable to using a CiviReport.  However, if there's a reason you want to use a CiviReport that works like the Sybunt report but with date ranges you can define on your own, it's called the "Repeat Contributions Report".